# Gather the sum of the deployments required memory from metric-server

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

Prometheus.

Any hint about how to collect the total required memory specified in the deployments? I mean the memory you specify as limit or required in the deployments.

I can do it using heapster and influxdb but I have not found how to do it with Prometheus and metric server, I do not find any metric with this information.

Is there any way to gather this information without using heapster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with [Kube State Metrics](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics). Just deploy it in your cluster and scrape its metrics with Prometheus.

These metrics give what you are finding:

- kube_pod_container_resource_requests_memory_bytes
- kube_pod_container_resource_limits_memory_bytes

Comment: Thank you, do you have any pointer to documentation about the metrics collected?. What metrics are available and what contains.

Comment: The above link is now broken. This should be the new link: https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/tree/master/docs